# Multiple Partitions in Spark RDD

Tags: scala, playframework, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

So I am trying to get data from a MySQL database using Spark within a Play/Scala project. Since the amount of rows I am trying to receive is huge, my aim is to get an Iterator from the spark rdd. Here is the Spark context and configuration...

```
  private val configuration = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("Reporting")
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
    .set("spark.akka.timeout", "5")
    .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")

  val sparkContext = new SparkContext(configuration)
```

The JDBCRDD is as follows along with the sql query

```
val query =
  """
    |SELECT id, date
    |FROM itembid
    |WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?
  """.stripMargin


val rdd = new JdbcRDD[ItemLeadReportOutput](SparkProcessor.sparkContext,
      driverFactory,
      query,
      rangeMinValue.get,
      rangeMaxValue.get,
      partitionCount,
      rowMapper)
      .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

The data is too much to get it at once. At the beginning with smaller data sets it was possible the get an iterator from rdd.toLocalIterator. However in this specific case it can not compute an iterator. So my aim is to have multiple partitions and recevie data part by part. I keep getting errors. What is the correct way of doing this ?

Comment: What kind of errors you get? Why do you need LocalIterator? can you do all your work in foreachPartition {..}?

Comment: You shoudn't set spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts to true. You cannot have multiple Spark context in a single JVM.

Comment: I keep getting either an empty iterator or a heap error. I need a local iterator because I don't want to load the data at once. I send this data to elasticsearch and I want to do it part by part or I might think of streaming it. @ipoteka

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are facing a heap problem read your MySQL table.

What I'll do in your case is to fetch the data from MySQL into the storage system (HDFS, local) files and then I'll use spark's context textFile to fetch it!

Example :

```
object JDBCExample {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    val url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/database"
    val username = "user"
    val password = "pass"

    var connection: Connection = null

    try {
      Class.forName(driver)
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)

      // This is the tricky part of reading a huge MySQL table you'll need to set your sql statement as following :
      val statement = connection.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)
      statement.setMaxRows(0)
      statement.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)

      val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from ex_table")

      val fileWriter = new FileWriter("output.csv")
      val writer = new CSVWriter(fileWriter, '\t');

      while (resultSet.next()) {
        val entries = List(... // process result here //...)
        writer.writeNext(entries.toArray)
      }
      writer.close();

    } catch {
      case e: Throwable => e.printStackTrace
    }
    connection.close()
  }
}
```

Once your data is stored you can read it:

```
val data = sc.textFile("output.csv")
```

PS: I've used some shortcuts (CSVWriter per example) in the code but you can use it as a skeleton to what you are intending to do!

Comment: Why would I bother writing it into a csv file and then read it all over again ? @eliasah

Comment: Because adding each row alone into an RDD is more expensive than writing it into a CSV and reading the whole CSV into an RDD. Plus it gives you persistency over your data. You might not need to load it each time from MySQL